# tidyr separate error when use sep parenthesis

Tags: r, tidyr

I cannot separate columns using parenthesis as separation character:

```
d = data.frame(a = c('af(dsf', 'sdf (asdf', 'sdf(df'))
d %>% separate(a, c('a','b'), sep = '(')
```

> Error in stringi::stri_split_regex(value, sep, n_max) :    Incorrectly
>   nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)

There is a bug? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `sep = '\\('` instead

Comment: Thanks. it works.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't need to specify the `sep` explicitly here as it will automatically detects

```
separate(d, a, c("a", "b"))
#    a    b
#1  af  dsf
#2 sdf asdf
#3 sdf   df
```

If needed to specify, either escape (`\\(`) as in the comments or place it in a square bracket

```
separate(d, a, c("a", "b"), sep="[(]")
#    a    b
#1   af  dsf
#2 sdf  asdf
#3  sdf   df
```